# Execute jar file with providing property file on another directory

Tags: java

Have a jar file which has some dependency on the property file.

When I place the jar file and property file same folder and trying to run it is running fine.

Command: `java -jar ImageUtilityFinal.jar`

When I am trying to place the property file on another folder it is throwing error.

Command: `java -jar ImageUtilityFinal.jar --config.location="C:\MIImageUtility\runableJar\config\ENV.properties"`

Location of the jar file: `C:\MIImageUtility\runableJar\`

CodeBlock  : `static String envfilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ENV.properties";`

Am getting following error,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\MIImageUtility\runableJar\ENV.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
        at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
        at Ambra.Ambra.DicomPushLoadTest.main(DicomPushLoadTest.java:74)
```

Comment: Might be a problem with how your code interprets the `--config.location` parameter. It has to understand this parameter, extract the value passed `C:\MIImageUtility\runableJar\config\ENV.properties`, and use that file as config file. In your code, it might not be detecting that parameter and might be opening file 'ENV.properties' without any directory specified (i.e. the current working directory), and it does not find it there, as it is in a sub-directory.

Comment: Are you using some kind of library to parse the command line arguments?  E.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/.  Using a library like this might help.

Comment: and `C:\MIImageUtility\runableJar\ENV.properties` is really a **file** on the filesystem, or is it inside the other JAR?

Comment: This is the declaration inside my code : static String envfilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ENV.properties";

Comment: Edit the question as you've not shown the relevant code which would help get an answer. You suggest it uses a command line parameter in question but say it depends on user.dir in the comment, and `dir` would confirm very quickly if your path exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

In your code block, i.e.

```java
static String envfilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ENV.properties";
```

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns the working directory, i.e. the folder that your JAR file is in. Hence when you place file *ENV.properties* in the same folder as the JAR file, your code works.

I suggest that you make *config.location* a System property, that can be set via the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html) command, using `-D` as stated in the documentation:

> -D*property=value*
> Sets a system property value. The *property* variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The *value* variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If *value* is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example `-Dfoo="foo bar"`).

Hence the command to launch your JAR becomes:

```
java -Dconfig.location="C:\MIImageUtility\runableJar\config\ENV.properties" -jar ImageUtilityFinal.jar
```

And your code becomes:

```java
static String envfilePath = System.getProperty("config.location");
```

You could also have a *fallback* location, e.g.

```java
static String envfilePath = System.getProperty("config.location");
if (envfilePath == null) {
    envfilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ENV.properties";
}
```

Comment: As the variable is static it is more concise as one liner, `static final Path envfilePath = Path.of(System.getProperty("config.location", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/ENV.properties"));` (using / so it works on Windows/Linux)

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
java "--config.location=C:\MIImageUtility\runableJar\config\ENV.properties" -jar ImageUtilityFinal.jar
```

Comment: I ma getting  "Unrecognized option: --config.location="

Comment: The path already made it into the error message, so passing it differently is clearly not going to help.

Comment: This will not work as --config.location is passed as a command line parameter to java, and not as a command line parameter of class launched by the `-jar` parameter, hence  "Unrecognized option: --config.location="